# form input text input weid display under IE and FF ok

Tags: html, css, forms, input

1,the input text under the IE7. it's weird. the text is on the top of the textbox.

http://run.xxmn.com/images/ie.jpg

2,the display under the FireFox .which is ok.

http://run.xxmn.com/images/firefox.jpg

i have written this style,but it still work.

```
  ......

  float:left;

 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

 font-size:13px;

 height:25px;

 .....
```

Comment: use padding inside the textbox when using ie7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `line-height: 25px;` or `padding: 6px 0;`

Comment: padding: 6px 0 ,is too big,whcih made the textbox too heigh?

Comment: Then make it smaller, I was just guessing. Or remove the height altogether and size it by using only the padding :)